# Multivariable limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|^3+|y|^3}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|^3+|y|^3}=0$$

I sort of know how to do it using polar coordinates, but I was trying to find an upper bound. Any ideas? I also wouldn't mind if someone could give me a hand formalizing the proof using polar coordinates.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the AM-GM inequality to the denominator.

Comment: Could you show me please how that would help?

Comment: @LunaSage It would give you $|x|^3+|y|^3 \ge 2|x|^{3/2}|y|^{3/2}$. Since the numerator is equal to $|x|^2|y|^2$ we can therefore bound the fraction by $(|x||y|)^{1/2}/2$ which goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: is enough to prove that $\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta\ge$ const $>0$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: This would be to show that the limit is independent of the value of theta?

Comment: Yes. You can bound the fraction easily.

Comment: There is one theorical thing I don't understand though. If I replace $x=r*cos(\theta)$ and $x=r*sin(\theta)$, so that when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, then $r\to0$ isn't theta a constant? or theta can be anything? I mean, why do I have to prove that it should be independent of theta?

Comment: Independent of theta.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $\frac{x}{1+x^3}\le\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}$ for $x\ge0$, we have 
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|^3+|y|^3}\right|
&=\color{#00A000}{\frac{|y/x|}{1+|y/x|^3}}|y|\\
&\le\color{#00A000}{\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}}|y|
\end{align}
$$

---

**Polar Coordinates**

Show that
$$
\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)=\frac14\sin^2(2\theta)\le\frac14
$$
and
$$
\left|\sin^3(\theta)\right|+\left|\cos^3(\theta)\right|\ge\frac1{\sqrt2}
$$
Then, since $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|^3+|y|^3}\right|
&=\frac{r^4\left|\,\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\,\right|}{r^3(\left|\sin^3(\theta)\right|+\left|\cos^3(\theta)\right|)}\\
&\le\frac{1/4}{1/\sqrt2}r\\
&=\frac{\sqrt2}{4}r
\end{align}
$$